# Can `function a() {}` be seen as a shorthand of `a = function a() {}`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did a series of experiments in nodejs console:

```
> function a(){}
undefined

> a
[Function: a]

> a.name
'a'

> b = function(){}
[Function]               // see, the name is empty

> b.name
''                       // further proof

> b = function b(){}
[Function: b]

> b.name
'b'                      // now b behaves just like it's defined
                         // by "function b(){}"
```

Judging from what I can test, `function a() {}` serves as a shorthand of `a = function a() {}`. Is this how engines like V8 internally do? Is there a difference between `a` and `b` in the above experiment?

Answer (score -2):

Basically what you are doing in `a` is just declaring the function whereas for `b` you are declaring the function and on the same line defining it again as `b`.  To prove this you can try something like the following:

```
a = function b(){}
a.name // results in b
```

So really you can avoid declaring and assigning and simply declare the function as you do with `a`.  To answer your question, the second form is a longer, unnecessary way of writing the first form.

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that in this example `b` even though it is declared it cant be referenced by that name because it is on the right-hand side of the equals sign.